# How to make this update API more efficient and shorter without duplications

Tags: typescript, api, backend, nestjs

Below is a method in a service for an API on updating an account. How do i shorten the code instead of so much additional objects in the if conditions?

```
async updateAccount(uuid: string, body: IUpdateAccountDto) {
    const found = await this.getAccountById(uuid);
    const update = (resolve, reject) => {
      if (
        found.username ||
        found.password ||
        found.email ||
        found.phone ||
        found.product
      ) {
        resolve(
          'account updated',
          ((found.username = body.username),
          (found.password = body.password),
          (found.email = body.email),
          (found.phone = body.phone),
          (found.product = body.product)),
        );
      } else {
        reject('cannot update username');
      }
    };

    const updateAccount = new Promise(update);
    return updateAccount;
  }
```

Comment: You don't need the wrapper `update` and the `new Promise`. That is all pointless.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.values(obj)` and `Array.some(fn)` to achive this. *Note: using Array.every(fn) will achive && condition*

```js
var notValidFound = {
  username: "",
  password: undefined,
  email: "",
  phone: null,
  product: ""
};

var notValidValue = Object.values(notValidFound).some(o => o);

console.log(notValidValue);

var validFound = {
  username: "some_username",
  password: undefined,
  email: "a@abc.com",
  phone: null,
  product: ""
};

var validValue = Object.values(validFound).some(o => o);

console.log(validValue);
```

You can read more about [Object.values(obj)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) and [Array.prototype.some(fn)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)